# Ruby on Rails partial not rendering properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, partials

I have an Opportunity model and a User model. On my Opportunity index page, I have a table that lists all of the Users. When I click "Show" next to Users, the page that renders is a blank page, whereas it should say "test test test". Here is my code:

views/opportunities/index.html.erb:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
```

views/users/show.html.erb:

```
<% render @user %>
```

views/users/_user.html.erb:

```
test test test test
```

Please help!! Thanks!!

Comment: [An Introduction to ERB Templating](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<% render @user %>` will not display any result, use `<%= render @user %>` to display the result of the evaluated code.

Answer (score 2):

> Executes the ruby code within the brackets.

```
<%  %>
```

> Prints something into erb file.

```
<%=  %>
```

> Avoids line break after expression.

```
<%  -%>
```

> Comments out code within brackets; not sent to client (as opposed to HTML comments).

```
<%#  %>
```